# What is the purpose of this tile joint?

Tags: bathroom, tile

Noticed this in a public restroom today.  Never seen anything like this in tile before.  Is this just a flex joint?  Or is it a patch job?

[image: joint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a change in floor plans to 'kick up' the corner and keep water from sitting there.